# How to pass Regex named group variable from URL to TemplateView as argument

Tags: python, django, rest, templates, view

Say I have this URL

`url(r'users/(?P<id>\d+)/edit$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='edit.html'))`

Is there a way to send the `<id>` to the template within that url pattern definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kwargs are passed directly onto the template already. You can just to `{{ id }}`.

Comment: Ah, Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me the way Daniel Roseman described. I had to use:

```
{{ view.kwargs.id }}
```

in my template in order for the named group variable to work as desired.